# R plotly custom colours with factor order in stacked area graph

Tags: r, plotly

can you get both custom colours and factor order in plotly stacked area graphs?

e.g. the code below produces the right order but the wrong colours.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins_cols <- c("Adelie" = "blue",
                   "Gentoo" = "red",
                   "Chinstrap" = "green")

penguin_order <- c("Gentoo", "Adelie", "Chinstrap")

df <- penguins %>% 
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = penguin_order)) %>% 
  arrange(species)

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~bill_length_mm,
            y = ~bill_depth_mm,
            name = ~species,
            fillcolor = ~penguins_cols[species],
            mode = "none",
            type = "scatter",
            stackgroup = 'one')
```

[image]

This is related to my previous question: [plotly stacked area graph custom colours from named vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74539064/plotly-stacked-area-graph-custom-colours-from-named-vector/74539250#74539250) for just the colours (not the order).

I tried this: [Ordering in r plotly barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149556/ordering-in-r-plotly-barchart) but it doesn't seem to work with the stacked area chart.

This produces the correct factor order (could reverse this), but not the colours. Is it possible to do both?

```
plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~bill_length_mm,
            y = ~bill_depth_mm,
            name = ~species,
            # fillcolor = ~penguins_cols[species],
            mode = "none",
            type = "scatter",
            stackgroup = 'one')
```

[image]

Real data added with some testing from @Kat's answer:

```
# data ---------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)



# factor levels
analyte_short_levels <- c("PCE", "TCE", "cis-1,2-DCE", "1,1-DCE", "trans-1,2-DCE", "Vinyl Chloride", "Ethene", "Ethane", "Acetylene", "Chloride")

# data
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~analyte_short, ~SAMPLE_DATE, ~REPORT_RESULT_VALUE, ~molar_mass,              ~value,
  "1,1-DCE", "2019-10-05",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "1,1-DCE", "2020-06-02",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "1,1-DCE", "2020-09-12",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "1,1-DCE", "2021-04-24",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "1,1-DCE", "2021-08-25",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "1,1-DCE", "2022-05-04",                 0.24, 96.94387817, 0.00247565916002595,
  "Acetylene", "2019-10-05",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Acetylene", "2020-06-02",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Acetylene", "2020-09-12",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Acetylene", "2021-04-24",                 0.73,      26.036,  0.0280381010907974,
  "Acetylene", "2021-08-25",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Acetylene", "2022-05-04",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2019-10-05",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2020-06-02",                 0.23, 96.94387817, 0.00237250669502487,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2020-09-12",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2021-04-24",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2021-08-25",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "cis-1,2-DCE", "2022-05-04",                  0.4, 96.94387817, 0.00412609860004325,
  "Ethane", "2019-10-05",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethane", "2020-06-02",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethane", "2020-09-12",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethane", "2021-04-24",                 0.57,      30.068,  0.0189570307303445,
  "Ethane", "2021-08-25",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethane", "2022-05-04",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethene", "2019-10-05",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethene", "2020-06-02",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethene", "2020-09-12",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethene", "2021-04-24",                  0.4,      28.052,  0.0142592328532725,
  "Ethene", "2021-08-25",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "Ethene", "2022-05-04",                   NA,          NA,                   0,
  "PCE", "2019-10-05",                  5.7, 165.8339996,  0.0343717212016154,
  "PCE", "2020-06-02",                  5.2, 165.8339996,  0.0313566579383158,
  "PCE", "2020-09-12",                  5.6, 165.8339996,  0.0337687085489555,
  "PCE", "2021-04-24",                    9, 165.8339996,  0.0542711387393927,
  "PCE", "2021-08-25",                  6.8, 165.8339996,  0.0410048603808745,
  "PCE", "2022-05-04",                  8.4, 165.8339996,  0.0506530628234332,
  "TCE", "2019-10-05",                   15, 131.3889465,   0.114164854803825,
  "TCE", "2020-06-02",                   16, 131.3889465,    0.12177584512408,
  "TCE", "2020-09-12",                   14, 131.3889465,    0.10655386448357,
  "TCE", "2021-04-24",                   28, 131.3889465,    0.21310772896714,
  "TCE", "2021-08-25",                   17, 131.3889465,   0.129386835444335,
  "TCE", "2022-05-04",                   31, 131.3889465,   0.235940699927905,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2019-10-05",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2020-06-02",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2020-09-12",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2021-04-24",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2021-08-25",                 0.15, 96.94387817, 0.00154728697501622,
  "trans-1,2-DCE", "2022-05-04",                 0.21, 96.94387817,  0.0021662017650227,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2019-10-05",                  0.1,          NA,                   0,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2020-06-02",                  0.1,          NA,                   0,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2020-09-12",                  0.1,          NA,                   0,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2021-04-24",                  0.1,          NA,                   0,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2021-08-25",                  0.1,          NA,                   0,
  "Vinyl Chloride", "2022-05-04",                 0.28,          NA,                   0
) %>% 
  mutate(SAMPLE_DATE = ymd(SAMPLE_DATE),
         analyte_short = factor(analyte_short, levels = analyte_short_levels))

# named vector ----------------------------
colour_chlorinated <- c("PCE" = "#b60a1c",
                        "TCE" = "#e03531",
                        "cis-1,2-DCE" = "#ff684c",
                        "1,1-DCE" = "#e39802",
                        "trans-1,2-DCE" = "#f0bd27",
                        "Vinyl Chloride" =  "#ffda66",
                        "Ethene" = "#309143",
                        "Ethane" = "#51b364", 
                        "Acetylene" = "#8ace7e")

# graph but order incorrect ---------------------
plot <- plot_ly(data = df) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~SAMPLE_DATE,
            y = ~value,
            name = ~analyte_short,
            fillcolor = ~colour_chlorinated[analyte_short],
            mode = "none",
            stackgroup = 'one') 

plot

# edited version of Kat's answer  --------------------------
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)            # gather data for the plot
  
  newOrd <- vector(mode = "integer")  # list to store new data order
  
  analyte_short_levels <- rev(levels(df$analyte_short))  # the order you're looking for in reverse
  
  invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(j) {
      nm <- plt$x$data[[j]]$name           # get the name of the trace
      newOrd[j] <<- which(analyte_short == nm)   # get correct index position
    }))
  plt$x$data <- list(plt$x$data[[newOrd[1]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[2]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[3]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[4]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[5]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[6]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[7]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[8]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[9]]])
  plt                        # return the updated plot
}

plot %>% 
  fixer() # blank


# fixer2 - same as Kat's fixer2() but diff column names and more in update plot-------------------------
fixer2 <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt) 
  
  newOrd <- vector(mode = "integer") # list to store new data order
  # the order you're looking for in reverse
  analyte_short <- rev(levels(df$analyte_short))    # <--- this changed
  invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(j) {
      nm <- plt$x$data[[j]]$name # get the name of the trace
      newOrd[j] <<- which(analyte_short == nm)   # get correct index position
    }))
  plt$x$data <- list(plt$x$data[[newOrd[1]]], # update plot
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[2]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[3]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[4]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[5]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[6]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[7]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[8]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[9]]])
  plt                        # return the updated plot
}

plot %>% 
  fixer2() # blank


# edited version of Kat's fixer2() -----------------
fixer3 <- function(plt, df, factor_column) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt) 
  
  newOrd <- vector(mode = "integer") # list to store new data order
  # the order you're looking for in reverse
  order <- rev(levels(df[[factor_column]]))    # <--- this changed
  
  invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(j) {
      nm <- plt$x$data[[j]]$name # get the name of the trace
      newOrd[j] <<- which(order == nm)   # get correct index position
    }))
  plt$x$data <- list(map(1:length(unique(df[[factor_column]])), ~plt$x$data[[newOrd[.x]]]))
  plt                        # return the updated plot
}


plot %>% 
  fixer3(df, "analyte_short") # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would just check...but I was sure making it an *ordered* factor was the answer...but it wasn't. So odd. I tried several things, but none worked.

I was able to create a workaround. I've added several comments to this UDF to explain a bit of what it's doing.

```
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)            # gather data for the plot
  
  newOrd <- vector(mode = "integer")  # list to store new data order
  
  species <- rev(levels(df$species))  # the order you're looking for in reverse

  invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(j) {
      nm <- plt$x$data[[j]]$name           # get the name of the trace
      newOrd[j] <<- which(species == nm)   # get correct index position
    }))
  plt$x$data <- list(plt$x$data[[newOrd[1]]], # update plot
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[2]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[3]]])
  plt                        # return the updated plot
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~bill_length_mm,
            y = ~bill_depth_mm,
            name = ~species,
            fillcolor = ~penguins_cols[species],
            mode = "none",
            type = "scatter",
            stackgroup = 'one') %>% 
  fixer()                                    # <<<----- I'm new!
```

[image]

I thought that `penguins` is probably not the data you're really working with, so here's another demonstration of this same concept with the `iris` data using the same structure you used for `penguins`.

```
plot_ly(iris) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width,
            y = ~Sepal.Length,
            name = ~Species,
            fillcolor = ~c("versicolor" = "red",
                           "setosa" = "blue", 
                           "virginica" = "green")[Species],
            mode = "none",
            type = "scatter",
            stackgroup = 'one')
```

[image]

I've made a single change to the UDF and updated the function name to `fixer2`. That change is marked in the comments.

```
fixer2 <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt) 
  
  newOrd <- vector(mode = "integer") # list to store new data order
                                     # the order you're looking for in reverse
  species <- rev(levels(iris$Species))    # <--- this changed
  invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(j) {
      nm <- plt$x$data[[j]]$name # get the name of the trace
      newOrd[j] <<- which(species == nm)   # get correct index position
    }))
  plt$x$data <- list(plt$x$data[[newOrd[1]]], # update plot
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[2]]],
                     plt$x$data[[newOrd[3]]])
  plt                        # return the updated plot
}
```

The new plot:

```
plot_ly(iris) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width,
            y = ~Sepal.Length,
            name = ~Species,
            fillcolor = ~c("versicolor" = "red",
                           "setosa" = "blue", 
                           "virginica" = "green")[Species],
            mode = "none",
            type = "scatter",
            stackgroup = 'one') %>% 
  fixer2()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kat. it looks like it should work. I will test it out with my dataset first.

Comment: Hi Kat, I couldn't get it to work, but I added a couple of extra bits of information. I'm not sure what it is but will keep trying.

Comment: I got it to work. It was something similar to this. Thanks.